# Bootstrap Sidebar - Fixed Desktop and Responsive Overlay on Device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed Bootstrap Sidebar tutorial by **Ondrej** from **Bootstrapions** *https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar*. Everything went well and function properly.

However I wanted to make the sidebar fixed on desktop, but overlay on device when clicked.

Have tried hiding the sidebar on desktop to display none and only show on device but result comes out ugly

***here the code to overlay css from **Ondrej** ***

```
#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}

#dismiss {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #7386D5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}


#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">

          <div id="dismiss">
              <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="sidebar-header">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-middle logo" alt="olaskee studio logo">
                Olaskee Studio
          </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

***overlay javascript***

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                    theme: "minimal"
                });

                $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
                    // hide sidebar
                    $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
                    // hide overlay
                    $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
                });

                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    // open sidebar
                    $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                    // fade in the overlay
                    $('.overlay').addClass('active');
                    $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                    $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                });
            });
    </script>
```

------------------------------ FIXED SIDEBAR ------------------------

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#content.active {
    width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content.active {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

same html without the dismiss and overlay tag

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "minimal"
            });

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
                $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: why am i down voted. Have i done anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Basic Demo and I made some modifications. I hope this is the goal you want to achieve. I leave the CSS code. I do not think it's necessary to touch the JS

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvqbKy

---

```
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* #sidebarCollapse */
#sidebarCollapse{
    transition: all 0.5s;
    left: 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding-left: 19%; 
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebarCollapse {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
    #content {
        padding: 20px !important;
    }

    #sidebar.active ~ #content #sidebarCollapse{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 53%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That what i wanted. i will now apply it to my project and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: @ayinlaoshodi You can mark the answer as a solution, and give me your vote. Thank you!